# How to FORMAT then CONCAT in Laravel DB Query?

Tags: laravel, database, format, concatenation

I formatted the `total_price` column using this;

```
DB::raw("FORMAT(sales_quotations.total_price, 2) as price),
```

After this, I need to CONCAT the `currency_name` to the formatted `total_price`.
But if I do this;

```
DB::raw("CONCAT(settings_currencies.currency_name,' ',  price) as totalPrice"),
```

It was throwing the below error because it can't find the `price`. Which is I think not possible to have it in this way.

```
LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'
```

Is there any way to achieve this in one line?

I have tried this;

```
DB::raw("CONCAT(settings_currencies.currency_name,' ',  FORMAT(sales_quotations.total_price, 2)) as totalPrice")
```

But it doesn't work. Error is;

```
LOG.error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1270 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'concat'
```

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above issue. In my case, I have some empty `currency_name`, if this is empty it will throw the error below (as I mentioned above).

```
LOG.error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1270 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT), (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'concat'
```

This is because of the difference in the collation, which you can solve by converting the string/column to one collation say utf8.

My line code goes like this;

```
 ->selectRaw('CONCAT(CAST(settings_currencies.currency_name AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8)," ",  FORMAT(sales_quotations.total_price, 2)) as totalPrice');
```